# "no function to return from, jumping to top level"

Tags: r

Could someone help me, I do not understand what is the problem here. I just started learning R (a few days ago). Here I have to construct a function that will give me all Marsenne primes after I created Marsenne numbers. There are 3 functions that I created:
1) factorlist simply find all the factors of a number
2) Marsenne number is a function that creates Marsenne numbers
3) CheckForMersennePrimes is a function that checks whether founded Mersenne numbers are prime or not.
***function "primes" gives all prime numers that are in interval from 0 to x

The problem is:
First 2 functions works perfectly. But third one does not work and gives the following below mistake. I cannot understand what is wrong at all. What I tried to do is since Mersenne numbers not all prime, I look into set of MersenneNumber and check every element in it whether it is prime or not and then remove it.

Can someone, please, help to find whats wrong?

Here are my functions:

```
factorlist<-function(x) {
  if (x<2) {return ("Invalid input")}
  if (x%%1!=0) {return ("Invalid input")}
  if (x==2) {return(2)}
  if (x==3) {return(3)}
  vec<-0
  for(i in 1:x){
    if(x%%i==0){
      vec[length(vec)]<-i
      vec<-c(vec,0)
    }
  }
  vec<-vec[-length(vec)]
  vec<-vec[-length(vec)]
  return(vec)
}

primes <- function(n){
  primesR <- function(p, i = 1){
    f <- p %% p[i] == 0 & p != p[i]
    if (any(f)){
      p <- primesR(p[!f], i+1)
    }
    p
  }
  primesR(2:n)
}

MarsenneNumber<-function(x){
  vec<-c(0)
  for (i in 3:x){
    vec<-union(vec, c(2^primes(i)-1))
  }
  return(vec[-length(1)])
}

CheckForMersennePrimes<-function(x){
  b<-length(MarsenneNumber(x)){
    for (i in 1:b){
      vec<-MarsenneNumber(x){
        if (factorlist(vec[i])!=1){
          vec<-c(-vec[i])
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return(vec)
}
```

My mistake to last function:

```
Error: unexpected '}' in "      }"
>     }
Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
>   return(vec)
Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Here is an example of how this functions works.

```
> factorlist(20)
[1]  1  2  4  5 10

> primes(20)
[1]  2  3  5  7 11 13 17 19

> MarsenneNumber(20)
[1]      3      7     31    127   2047   8191 131071 524287
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CheckForMersennePrimes` has extra `{}` on line 2 and line 4 (inside for loop) of this function, like `vec<-MarsenneNumber(x){if()...}`

I removed those extra braces.

```
CheckForMersennePrimes <- function( x ){
  b <- length( MarsenneNumber( x ) )
  for ( i in 1:b ){
    vec <- MarsenneNumber( x )
    if ( factorlist( vec[i] ) != 1 ){
      vec <- c( -vec[i] )
    }
  }
  return( vec )
}
```

I think, your intention is to get values of `vec` in which `factorlist(vec[i])` is equal to 1. If this is true, then you have to initiate `vec` outside the for loop and check for this condition. Then finally return `a1` which contains all `vec` values passing the `if` condition.

I also shortened your code by removing `b` variable. You do not need it. Instead you could do `seq_along(vec)`. It will do the same thing without `b` variable.

```
CheckForMersennePrimes <- function( x ){
  vec <- MarsenneNumber( x )
  a1 <- c()
  for ( i in seq_along( vec ) ){
    if ( factorlist( vec[i] ) == 1 ){
      a1 <- c( a1, vec[i ] )
    }
  }
  return( a1 )
}
```

Further condensing the code will give same output. I removed `seq_along` and indexing of `vec`

```
CheckForMersennePrimes <- function( x ){
  vec <- MarsenneNumber( x )
  a1 <- c()
  for ( i in vec ){
    if ( factorlist( i ) == 1 ) {
      a1 <- c( a1, i )
    }
  }
  return( a1 )
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But will the function recognise my new variable "vec" in the line "if (factorlist(vec[i])!=1){" since they are both on the same "level" in code? I was thinking that if we introduce new variable and want to use it later, we have to use {}. Maybe I misunderstand something. Also, I still face the same problem..

Comment: Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"   still facing this problem.

Comment: I updated my question by adding examples and `primes` function. I use basic R studio, did not change anything it it and did not download anything to it.

Comment: Now it works without mistakes, but still does not do what it is supposed to do, now I will try to find out why if I can. Thank you very much!

Comment: I cannot upvote since have less than 15 rep, but I accepted it. Ok, I will try to start with new workspace.

Comment: You facing the issue because `factorlist(x)` gives a vector of length greater than 1. You should try the `if` condition as `any( factorlist( i ) %in% 1 ) )` for atleast one value equal to 1 or `all( factorlist( i ) %in% 1 ) )` for all values equal to 1

Comment: Sathish, that solved my problem absolutely! Thank you very much! Now I got it, no other questions. Perfect!